# How Automate Application Lifecycle Management using python

Tags: python, jira, alm

I want automate ALM(Application lifecycle Management).

Is there any ALM REST API like jira JIRA REST API ?.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are asking about Microfocus ALM (former HP ALM/QC) tool.
If so, here is a link for their REST API tech preview: https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/Content/REST_API_Tech_Preview/General/Overview.html

Comment: Hi sergi, thanks for the response ,is there any ALM python library like jira python library? .If not there please can you suggest me how to write our own ALM python library by using reference of jira python library? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Prashanth, unfortunately I'm not a Python developer, so not familiar with any library. We are developing a platform for integrating various tools with ALM, so you might want to look at it: https://www.agiletestware.com/bumblebee